# If $T(x) = Ax$ and $L(x) = Bx$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then when does $BA(x)=0$ imply...

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T(x) = Ax$ and $L(x) = Bx$ where $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then when does $BA(x)=0$ imply that $A^tB^t(x)=0$ where $A^t$ and $B^t$ are the transposes of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: If $C=BA$ is the matrix of an orthogonal projection then your implication holds.

Comment: Why $BA(x)$ instead of $L \circ T$?